# agregar saltos de línea a mensaje enviado en formato html con php

Tags: php, email

Estoy tratando de enviar un email desde php desde un form, quiero que la información que venga desde dicho form se muestre en un html,  todo funciona perfecto pero el mensaje que traigo que envío del textarea desde el form contenido aquí en la variable  $enviarMensaje y mostrado en el html dentro de un p se muestra siempre en una sola linea.

La pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para que el mensaje se muestre con una estructura similar a esta dentro del html

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et nulla quis nisl aliquet porta. Curabitur volutpat arcu vitae malesuada placerat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et nulla quis nisl aliquet porta. Curabitur volutpat arcu vitae malesuada placerat.

a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
b. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  
c. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
d.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Gracias por su respuesta.

```
static public function responderMensajesController(){

    if(isset($_POST["enviarnombreEmpresa"])){
        $mail = $_POST["enviarEmail"];
        $nombresMail = $_POST["enviarNombres"];
        $apellidosMail = $_POST["enviarApellidos"];

        $enviarTitulo = $_POST["enviarTituloRespuesta"];
        $enviarMensaje = $_POST["enviarMensajeRespuesta"];


        $para = $mail . ',' . '<br>';
        $para .= 'CC' . ' jhonfe648@gmail.com' . '<br>';
        $titulo = $enviarTitulo. '<br>';

        $enviarMensaje = '<html>
            <head>
            <title>Respues a su mensaje</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 30px">
                            <div class="col-12" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
                                <a class="float-right" href="" style="font-family: Righteous; font-size: 25px; color: #fff; background:#243B55; padding: 4px 10px; text-decoration: none">nix<span style="color:#007bff ">blue</spanspan></a>
                            </div>
                            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 25px">Hola '.$nombresMail." ".$apellidosMail.'</h4>
                            <h6>Gracias por comunicarte con Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</h6>
                            <p style="margin-bottom: 30px">'.$enviarMensaje.'</p>
                            <hr>
                            <footer>
                                <div class="col-12 p-0">
                                    <h5>Cordialmente:</h5>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, S.A.S ceo</p>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Bogotá Colombia</p>
                                    <p class="mb-0">WhatsApp: +57 0000000</p>
                                    <p class="mb-0">correo@correo.com</p>
                                    <a href="#">www.Loremipsumdolorsitamet.com</a>
                                </div>
                            </footer>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>';


            $cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" . '<br>';

             $cabeceras .= 'From: juanu@juanu.com' . "\r\n". '<br>';

            $envio = mail($para, $titulo, $enviarMensaje, $cabeceras);

            if($envio){
                echo'<script>

                        swal({
                          title: "¡OK!",
                          text: "¡El mensaje ha sido enviado correctamente!",
                          type: "success",
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                          closeOnConfirm: false
                        },

                        function(isConfirm){
                             if (isConfirm) {      
                                window.location = "mensajes";
                              } 
                        });

                </script>';
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy probablemente tengas que usar la función de php [nl2br](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) sobre la variable que contiene el texto del formulario. Básicamente lo que hace es sustituir los saltos de linea (\r\n, \n\r, \n y \r) por el salto de línea html

Comment: exelente funciona perfecto gracias 